# displaying different product types

Tags: php

i've got featured products

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM credit_card_offers WHERE featured = 1";
$featured = $db->query($sql);
```

then a while loop

```
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

to display the featured products. how would i be able to show popular products ect.. on the same page when show popular products is selected?

i can do it on a diffrent .php page but im looking to do it on the same page if possible?

Comment: you want to show featured and popular products, or only one of them, depending on the selection?

Comment: Do you want to show the products on the click of the "show popular products" or you can have a submit button??

Comment: @KristjanKica i only would like to show what ever is selected, and submit button or onclick

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that.

```
 <form action="file.php" method="post">
 <input type="radio" name="choice" value="popular">Popular<input type="radio" 
 name="choice" value="featured">Featured
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

in the php code change featured with $_POST["choice"]

Comment: try the code i edited. Do you have featured and popular as fields in the table?

Comment: yes i have featured and most_popular_sort in the database

Comment: what do you save in most_popular_sort? and how do you find the most popular products?

Comment: they are all in the same row i have got featured most_popular_sort balance_transfer_sort purchases_sort cashback_sort rewards_sort ect... i got them as defined as 0 and then call them as 1 eg. `SELECT * FROM credit_card_offers WHERE featured = 1`

Comment: i got them in the same row as my product

Comment: I understand that. I am saying what criteria you use to make them popular and unmake them popular.
If im understandind you well, change the value from "popular" to "most_popular_sort"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139102/discussion-between-kristjan-kica-and-terry).

Comment: heres a bit of the code from credit-cards.php if that helps [link](http://pastebin.com/ZtQdwfN2)

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried fetching all your table then loop twice on the result,
displaying only featured on the first loop

Comment: im not sure how to do that?

Comment: use ` $res =  mysqli_fetch_all ( MYSQLI_ASSOC )` then loop over it with a condition like => `$res[$i]['featured'] == true`